# Feching Image form sqlite ( using FMDatabase class) 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlite

Problem : - I am using FMDatabase class to store the data in database and access data from db. In one table I used Blob data type for storing Image. 
way:

```
     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
     NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    [fmdbase executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Insert into tblComm('%d,%@','%@')",cID,cmmentsString,data...]];
```

And Access the data like this ,

```
     commentsText.text = [records stringForColumn:@"comments"];
   //  NSData *data = [records stringForColumn:@"photo"];
      NSData *data = [records dataForColumn:@"photo"];
     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

but data is not accurate format and not showing image , Please help ?

Comment: Solution: like this : Create table tblComm (commID integer primary key autoincrement, comm text, photo text); and  Insert values using FMDatabase class using BASE64Encoding, please download the code from this link [link] (http://imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php) and write the code like this : //Convert the nsdata to nsstring: UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
[Base64 initialize];
NSString *enString = [Base64 encode:data1];

Answer (score 1):

One option (and generally preferred when working in SQL) is to write the image to a file on the system and store the path (or some other kind of identifier) in the database.

Some internals of how sqlite stores records & why it might not be optimized for storing images. Apple's recommendation is not to store BLOB's in SQLite databases that are bigger than ~2 kilobytes.

SQLite organizes databases into pages. Each page is 4 kilobytes in size.  When you read data from the SQLite database file it loads these pages into an internal page cache.  On the iPhone I think this cache defaults to 1 megabyte in size.  This makes reading adjacent records very fast because they will probably be in the page cache already.

When SQLite reads your database record into memory it reads the entire record and all of the pages that it occupies.  So if your record contains a BLOB, it could occupy many pages and you will be ejecting existing pages from the cache and replacing them with your BLOB record's pages.

This isn't so bad if you're just scanning through and loading all your BLOBS to do something with them (display them for example).  But if say you did a query where you just wanted to get some data that is in the same row as the BLOB this query would be much slower than if the record did not contain the large BLOB. So at a minimum you should store your BLOB data in a separate table. Or better yet, store the BLOB data as files outside of the SQLite database as my first suggestion was.

Note that it may be possible to tweak the page cache size with [SQL PRAGMA statements](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) (if you're not using CoreData).